# Is it possible to run Java applets in the Android WebKit Browser?

Tags: java, android, applet

Is it possible to run Java applets in the Android WebKit Browser?  If not does anyone know when java applets will be supported?

Comment: Currently its not possible to run java applets in the Android Webkit Browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Android does not have a full Java VM, and therefore does not currently support Applets in the browser.  While changing this is certainly possible, I have not heard of any plans to do so.